# Strike through TextView item in ListView by checking database status

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I am a beginner in Android, I have a `ListView` which loads data from `SQLite` database with this code on `onCreate`:

```
Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.getAllTasks();
String[] fromFields = new String[] {dbAdapter.dbHelper.KEY_TASK};

int[] toView = new int[] {R.id.task};
SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.task_items, cursor, fromFields, toView, 0);

ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.taskList);
myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

I have db fields `task (text), done (boolean) and date (text)`.

I can toggle strike through in the TextView on item click of ListView using this code and I can change the db field `done` value here:

```
ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.taskList);
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         TextView v = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.task);

         if ((v.getPaintFlags() & Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG) > 0){
            v.setPaintFlags( v.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
         } else {
            v.setPaintFlags(v.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
         }
         // calling update method to change done value in db
     }
});
```

Now how can I strike through all items which is marked as done (`done = 1`) when loading ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `SimpleCursorAdapter`, attach [a `ViewBinder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html) to it that applies your strikethrough. Your `setViewValue()` would examine your `Cursor` to see if it is done or not, then would call `setPaintFlags()` accordingly on the `TextView` (downcast from the `View` that is passed in). In addition, you would either need to set the text on the `TextView` yourself, or specifically return `false` to indicate that default binding should be applied.

Comment: I am a beginner, can you explain the code for this?

Comment: @devo: I thought I had. After all, you already have most of the code for it in your question, in the form of your `setPaintFlags()` bits. If there are **specific** things that you do not understand about the answer, feel free to post a comment explaining what those **specific** things are.

Comment: I don't know how to use the setViewValue method and when it will be called.

Comment: @devo: You don't use it yourself. You [call `setViewBinder()` on the `SimpleCursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#setViewBinder%28android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder%29) to attach your `ViewBinder` to it. Then, when it comes time for the adapter to render your `ListView` rows, it will call `setViewValue()` for each row, to allow you to participate in the binding process.

Comment: Okay got it, here how can I check the done field value to set strike through inside the setViewValue? ``TextView v = ((TextView) view);
                v.setPaintFlags(v.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);``

Comment: @devo: Since I don't know the nature of your `Cursor`, I cannot help you much. The `Cursor` will already be positioned on the proper row. Retrieve the "done" value from the `Cursor` and use an `if` test to determine whether or not the current row needs the strikethrough.