# Iterating through every item in a ListView - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, iteration

I need my application to apply a strike through to the contents of each item in my ListView based on whether or not the content of each item is marked as checked off or not in my SQLite database. Right now I obtain the text for each item in the list view from a database table, store it in a List, pass that into a ArrayAdapter, and then use that to set my ListView adapter. This is my code:

```
private ListView taskList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.task_list);

// Get text for each TextView from database
db.getWritableDatabase();
tasks = db.readTasks((int) listId);

// Set up adapter for ListView
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            view.getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            tasks);
taskList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My thought was to iterate through each item in the ListView after it has been set and check to see if the corresponding record in the database had it marked as checked or not, and then act accordingly on the item. I don't know how to iterate over the contents of a ListView however, nor am I certain this is the best way to do this. Does anyone know how to iterate over the contents of a ListView or is there an entirely better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe your question is similar to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722794/strike-through-textview-item-in-listview-by-checking-database-status?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Firstly define a Task object with useful properties:

```
class Task {
    public boolean isComplete() {...};
    @override String toString() {...};
}
```

Then make your db method return a list of such objects:

```
ArrayList<Task> tasks = db.readTasks((int) listId);
```

Finally, subclass the ArrayAdapter:

```
private static class TaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
    private ArrayList<Task> mTasks;
    TaskAdapter (Context c, ArrayList<Task> list) {
        super(c, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        mTasks = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView txt = v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        int flags = txt.getPaintFlags();
        if (mList.get(position).isComplete()) {
            flags = flags | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG;
        } else {
            flags = flags & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG;
        }
        txt.setPaintFlags(flags);
    }
}
```

You can also do a lot more when you subclass the adapter: eg. create your own view layout (eg. if you wanted a 'tick' graphic instead of a strikethough).

Google for examples of this kind of thing. There are many.